# Count duplicates based on range of datetime in R

Tags: r, datetime, duplicates

I need help in summarizing by counting the instances of users that have records within 7 days. The occurrence needs not to be the first occurrence only but any instance that occurred within 7 days.

```
User     Datetime
User1    3/4/2015 12:14
User1    3/24/2015 15:25
User2    4/15/2015 11:08
User2    4/17/2015 5:06
User2    4/20/2015 6:17
User2    4/28/2015 12:15
User3    5/12/2015 9:48
User3    5/18/2015 11:54
User3    5/18/2015 11:59
```

I tried using `aggregate` or `melt` but that only gives me the count if I treat datetime as factors by date only.

So, in the sample data above, User2 has a count of 2 and User3 has a count of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on your comment about treating `Datetime` as factors. The code below assumes that `Datetime` is a string in your data frame which I'll call `df.`  It converts `df$Datetime` to a Date object and then counts the records within a 7 day interval of each other.

```
df$Datetime <- as.Date(df$Datetime, format="%m/%d/%Y" )
record_count <- aggregate(df$Datetime, by = list(df$User), function(x) sum(diff(x)<7))
```

Comment: Thank you for this custom function! This works. Problem was, I was forcing datetime to be recognized as numeric